# Get Total Number of Occurrences of a Value from an Inner Array in a Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My MongoDB document looks like this

```
{  
   "_id":"sdf23sddfsd",
   "the_list":[  
      {  
         "Sentiment":[  
            "Negative",
            "Positive",
            "Positive"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Sentiment":[  
            "Neutral",
            "Positive"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "some_other_list":[  
      {  
         "Sentiment":[  
            "Positive",
            "Positive",
            "Positive"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to know total occurrence count of "Positive" for "the_list" field, which in above case is three i.e. there are three occurrences of "Positive".

Obviously, I get One document count from

```
db.tmp.find({ "the_list.Sentiment": { "$in": ["Positive"] } }).count()
```

And also get One from:

```
db.tmp.aggregate(
    { $match: { "the_list.Sentiment": { "$in": ["Positive"] } } }
    , { $group: { _id: "_id", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
)
```

Finally, below I was experimenting with, still get zero

```
db.tmp.aggregate(
  {
        $group: {
            _id: "_id", count: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{"$in": ["Positive","$the_list.Sentiment"]} , 1, 0]
                }
            }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Are you really just interested in this one document? Can't you just fetch this document and treat it like a normal JavaScript object?

Comment: No, there are millions of documents and I need to total count from all the documents, I just gave one example. Notice my query runs on the entire collection it doesn't filter one document. I wonder if there should be a way do it, if not by mongo query, then by writing javascript function and saving on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would go a little more flexible where you could look at "all" the possible values and count them at the same time. Which basically gives two points of adjustment for:

- Including both `"the_list` and `"some_other_list"` in the results where I wanted to
- Adjusting values to filter of `"Positive"`, `"Negative"` and `"Neutral"` in any combination as I wanted as well

Keeping in mind here that aggregation pipelines like "all" MongoDB query DSL is essentially just a "data structure", so if there are "clean points" where I can replace "a list" `[]` with variable input to alter output to different needs, then I do so.

So showing that with the other optional adjustments commented out:

```
db.getCollection('tmp').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "Sentiment": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": {
                    "$concatArrays": [
                      "$the_list.Sentiment",
                      //"$some_other_list.Sentiment"
                    ]
                  },
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": {
                    "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]      
                  }
                }
              },
              "as": "l",
              "cond": { "$in": [ "$$l", ["Positive"/*,"Negative","Neutral"*/] ] }
            }
          },
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": { "$in": [ "$$this", "$$value.k" ] },
              "then": {
                "$let": {
                   "vars": {
                     "index": { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$value.k", "$$this" ] }
                   },
                   "in": {
                     "$concatArrays": [
                       [{ 
                         "k": "$$this",
                         "v": { "$add": [
                           { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$value.v", "$$index" ] },
                           1
                         ]}
                       }],
                       { "$filter": {
                         "input": "$$value",
                         "as": "v",
                         "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$v.k", "$$this" ] }
                       }}
                     ]
                   }  
                } 
              },
              "else": {
                "$concatArrays": [ 
                  "$$value",
                  [{ "k": "$$this", "v": 1 }]
                ]
              }
            }    
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Would produces per document:

```
{
    "_id" : "sdf23sddfsd",
    "Sentiment" : {
        "Positive" : 3.0
    }
}
```

Or looking in both lists for all the values ( thus removing the comments ):

```
{
    "_id" : "sdf23sddfsd",
    "Sentiment" : {
        "Positive" : 6.0,
        "Negative" : 1.0,
        "Neutral" : 1.0
    }
}
```

And if you wanted that across the collection, then I'd remove the `$arrayToObject` and simply [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the reduced array in order to pass to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) for all possible values:

```
db.getCollection('tmp').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "Sentiment": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    "$the_list.Sentiment",
                    "$some_other_list.Sentiment"
                  ]
                },
                "initialValue": [],
                "in": {
                  "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]      
                }
              }
            },
            "as": "l",
            "cond": { "$in": [ "$$l", ["Positive","Negative","Neutral"] ] }
          }
        },
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$in": [ "$$this", "$$value.k" ] },
            "then": {
              "$let": {
                 "vars": {
                   "index": { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$value.k", "$$this" ] }
                 },
                 "in": {
                   "$concatArrays": [
                     [{ 
                       "k": "$$this",
                       "v": { "$add": [
                         { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$value.v", "$$index" ] },
                         1
                       ]}
                     }],
                     { "$filter": {
                       "input": "$$value",
                       "as": "v",
                       "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$v.k", "$$this" ] }
                     }}
                   ]
                 }  
              } 
            },
            "else": {
              "$concatArrays": [ 
                "$$value",
                [{ "k": "$$this", "v": 1 }]
              ]
            }
          }    
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$Sentiment" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$Sentiment.k",
    "count": { "$sum": "$Sentiment.v" }  
  }}
])
```

Which would produce one document per possible value and it's total count within all documents:

```
{ "_id" : "Neutral", "count" : 1.0 }
{ "_id" : "Negative", "count" : 1.0 }
{ "_id" : "Positive", "count" : 6.0 }
```

We can even get a single document with "flexible keys" simply by adding two more stages at the end of that pipeline if we want:

```
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "Sentiment": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "Sentiment": { "$arrayToObject": "$Sentiment" }  
  }}
```

Almost overkill to turn three possible documents into one, but it does at least mirror the single document output:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "Sentiment" : {
        "Neutral" : 1.0,
        "Negative" : 1.0,
        "Positive" : 6.0
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer the "named keys" in a "single" document where you can just list all the ones you want within a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage:

```
db.getCollection('tmp').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "Sentiment": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": {
                    "$concatArrays": [
                      "$the_list.Sentiment",
                      "$some_other_list.Sentiment"
                    ]
                  },
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": {
                    "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]      
                  }
                }
              },
              "as": "l",
              "cond": { "$in": [ "$$l", ["Positive","Negative","Neutral"] ] }
            }
          },
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": { "$in": [ "$$this", "$$value.k" ] },
              "then": {
                "$let": {
                   "vars": {
                     "index": { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$value.k", "$$this" ] }
                   },
                   "in": {
                     "$concatArrays": [
                       [{ 
                         "k": "$$this",
                         "v": { "$add": [
                           { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$value.v", "$$index" ] },
                           1
                         ]}
                       }],
                       { "$filter": {
                         "input": "$$value",
                         "as": "v",
                         "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$v.k", "$$this" ] }
                       }}
                     ]
                   }  
                } 
              },
              "else": {
                "$concatArrays": [ 
                  "$$value",
                  [{ "k": "$$this", "v": 1 }]
                ]
              }
            }    
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "Positive": { "$sum": { "$ifNull": [ "$Sentiment.Positive", 0 ] } },
    "Negative": { "$sum": { "$ifNull": [ "$Sentiment.Negative", 0 ] } },
    "Neutral": { "$sum": { "$ifNull": [ "$Sentiment.Neutral", 0 ] } }    
  }}
])
```

With output:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "Positive" : 6.0,
    "Negative" : 1.0,
    "Neutral" : 1.0
}
```

And that allows you to go straight to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), and even in one stage if you really wanted to push the monster conditions in there.

---

Also if there was no need to "aggregate" at all, then it's much simpler to reshape documents as returned by the cursor. You should use "aggregation" for actual "aggregating", which may well be the case but it's good to show how much cleaner the client code is for cases where you did not actually need that:

```
db.getCollection('tmp').find({}).map( doc => 
  Object.assign({
    "_id": doc._id,
     "Sentiment": 
       [].concat.apply([],
        ["the_list","some_other_list"].map( l => 
          doc[l].reduce((acc,curr) => acc.concat(curr.Sentiment),[])
        )
      )
      .filter( k => ["Positive","Negative","Neutral"].indexOf(k) != -1)
      .reduce((acc,curr) => 
       (acc.hasOwnProperty(curr))
         ? Object.assign(acc, { [curr]: acc[curr] += 1 })
         : Object.assign(acc,{ [curr]: 1 })
       ,{})
  })
)
```

Where again we use the same "flexible" form that would allow you to easily adjust from "one" possible value to any number of possible combinations. And of course the same output result:

```
{
    "_id" : "sdf23sddfsd",
    "Sentiment" : {
        "Negative" : 1.0,
        "Positive" : 6.0,
        "Neutral" : 1.0
    }
}
```

So it's all subjective as to what you want to do. For me I'd rather get all the count's at once, or at least have the option to at least get different counts with a simple adjustment of either of the conditions, rather than running separate queries, and then later looking for a way to combine them.

That's my thinking on design, where I look for the solution that would suit the most flexible cases first and have easy points where I can adjust with input parameters.

Comment: This is great, I like it better. Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering if Sentiments was not a list/array anymore, instead just a field i.e "Sentiment":"Positive" or "Sentiment":"Negative", what changes I would have to do in your non-aggregate script.

Comment: @Watt If you have a different question then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which makes it a clear case where you can express what you really mean. In truth "nested arrays" are not great and should be rather avoided, let alone seeing some of the wrangling required to coerce "key names" to arrays. The point here was to cover everything with one query, rather than separate ones. Also whilst other answers did point for `$size` and `$filter` for simplified case, they also needlessly used `$reduce` to basically recreate `$size`. So this is a better use of `$reduce`.

Comment: I asked a new question for above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086498/how-to-re-write-a-mongo-client-code-using-mongodb-driver-3-4-java-api-for-map

Answer (score 3):

You need to filter the subdocument array to return those elements equal to "Positive" and return the sum of the resulted array  or the number of the elements equal to "Positive" for each subdocument in the "the_list" array using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter). From there, all you need is combine the sum using the [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operator

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "count": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$the_list",
              "in": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$this.Sentiment",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this",
                      "Positive"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$add": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$size": "$$this"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Prior to MongoDB 3.4, you need a different approach as shown in this pipeline

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "arrayOfSum": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$the_list",
            "in": {
              "$size": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$this.Sentiment",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this",
                      "Positive"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: For benefit of others, I tested the post 3.4 answer. Since I am using 3.4.5

Comment: I had to add as per @Veeram the ```$group``` step to get total count on all documents

Comment: You have a "typo" as a result of "copy and paste". The second example still says `"$$this"` even though `$reduce` is not used, and you forgot the `"as"` for the `$filter`, where you would actually declare the aliased variable. But otherwise, nice and clean. Though personally I would take a more flexible approach than simply matching "one" value, even if that was what was asked for. But nice job:)

Comment: Hello @NeilLunn, that was not a typo. You can use the `$$this` in `filter` or `$map` as well, in which cases you don't specify `as` expression.

Comment: @S.M.Styvane Your right of course. I forgot that one was added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$map` to sum the matched `$filter` sentiments in each document followed by `$group` to count across documents.

Something like

```
db.tmp.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "count": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$the_list",
            "as": "result",
            "in": {
              "$size": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$result.Sentiment",
                  "as": "senti",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$senti",
                      "Positive"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Mongo 3.4 version using `$reduce`

```
db.tmp.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "count": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$the_list",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$add": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$size": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$this.Sentiment",
                    "as": "senti",
                    "cond": {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$$senti",
                        "Positive"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```